# How to fix it java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: exception

This is my Code:-

```
 import java.util.Random;
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner hs = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random ran = new Random();


    int [] player = new int [3];
    int [] com = new int [3];
    //play mode

    System.out.println("Please select mode:  ");
    System.out.println("1. Practice mode.  ");
    System.out.println("2. Game mode.   ");
    System.out.println("3. End.    ");
    int input = hs.nextInt();       //mode
     int draw = 0  ;
     int Player1=0;
     int Com1=0;
    if(input == 1){
        System.out.println("You select Practice mode.");

        for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++){
            com[i] = ran.nextInt(2);
            if(com[i] == 0){
                System.out.print("剪刀  ");
            }else if(com[i] == 1){
                System.out.print("石頭  ");
            }else if(com[i] == 2){
                System.out.print("布  ");
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0 ; i <= 2 ; i++){
            player[i] = hs.nextInt();
            if(com[i] == 0){
                System.out.print("剪刀  ");
            }else if(com[i] == 1){
                System.out.print("石頭  ");
            }else if(com[i] == 2){
                System.out.print("布  ");
            }



        }
        hs.close();
        for(int i = 0 ; i <=2 ; i++){
            if(player[i]==com[i]){
            draw ++;

            }else if(player[i]-com[i]<0)
            {
              Com1 ++;

            }else{ 
                Player1++;


            }
        System.out.println("Player"+ Player1+"com"+ Com1 + "Draw"+ draw);
        }

    }else if(input == 2){
        System.out.println("Game Mode : input the way you want , three time");
    }else{
        System.out.println("fatal error , game will be close");
    }
}
```

I  tried   many times, but  There is mo  output.

This is a rock, paper, scissors game.

but there is no output ,
only Exception in thread `"main" java.util.InputMismatchException`

Comment: Are you sure you are giving input as 1 2 or 3? If you give a char input this exception can happen!

Answer (score 0):

It works at my end as it is. The exception `java.util.InputMismatchException` would occur if you are not providing it the expected input (e.g., providing real numbers when it expects integers). Other than that, it executes successfully.

Also as a suggestion, you should consider improving the subject of your question and format the question properly.